# Magento Local Dev Environment URL Redirecting

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin, localhost

I have successfully set up a local development environment for my Magento store and have separate /app/etc/local.xml files for dev and prod. I also have a copy of the database in the local phpymadmin.

Along with this I've set up vhosts so that when I go to http://store.dev it will find the right folder in localhost and display the site. I know that it connects to the database correctly because if I delete the database or change the local config file, magento will throw an error.

My problem is that every time I go to store.dev I get redirected to http://store.com . I know that there are the two url variables in core_config_data and I changed both of those to store.dev without success. I even went as far as doing a find and replace in the mysql dump to replace all of the instances of the .com with the .dev.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to flush your Magento cache and may be browser cache. To avoid browser redirect caching - use different one, or add random GET parameter to URL.

Just an idea, may be it will be interesting for you,

Remove URL from core_config_data. Create separate local.xml file for every environment, set node default/web/secure/base_url and node default/web/unsecure/base_url to certain URL (http://store.dev/ for dev, http://store.com/ for production). It's allow you to assign URL in your configuration file (instead of core_config_data). It will work because magento looks into this node for default value if value not specified in database.

But there is an important notice, if anybody will submit configuration form in web tab it will write to database value, so changes in local.xml wouldn't be applied anymore. You can remove URL field from config, but then you wouldn't be able to edit it within Web interface.

Comment: I've deleted all of the files in /var/cache and have tried several different browsers so that's not the problem. Any other ideas or other caches that I'm forgetting about? I can go to http://store.dev/admin but as soon as I login it redirects to the .com, which is strange.

Comment: Doesn't seems like Magento do this redirect, because there is no redirects in backoffice. Even if you are not logged in magento doesn't do any redirects (just run different controller). I think the problem not in Magento. Since it works for login page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the database table **core_config_data**.

To solve it, you have to search in the the "path" column the value "web/unsecure/base_url" and "web/unsecure/base_url". You have to correct them with **your new base_url**, clear the cache (via bash command `rm -rf var/cache` ) and it should work!